# MongoDB equivalent of SQL expression '1=1' in Java

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, aggregation-framework, logical-operators

In SQL you can do the following;

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID=43 AND 1=1
```

How can I feed boolean expressions like '1=1' or '4<6' as criteria to MongoDB logical operators in Java?

For instance, I can do;

```
collection.find("$or",Arrays.asList(new Document("field1",value1),new Document("field2",value2)))
```

however, the above criteria are always based on already existing fields, while what I would like to do instead is more something like this (*won't compile*);

```
collection.find("$and",Arrays.asList(new Document(1,1),new Document("field2",value2)))
```

The reason I need this, is because I have a list of '$or' criteria but this list might be empty - in this case I want to have no criteria at all.

---

**Update 1**

While @gil.fernandes's solution is great for `find` queries, it will not work in **aggregation queries** (which is also what I need);

```
AggregateIterable aggregationQuery = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
    [...]
    new Document("$match", new Document("$or", Arrays.asList(new Document("$where","1==1"))))
));
```

> MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16395:  '$where is
>   not  allowed inside of a $match aggregation expression'

Any ideas on how we can use the '1=1' logic in $match operators of aggregation?

**Update 2**

I applied @Veeram's second solution using mongo server version 3.4.7
However, if I include the `addFields` and `match` objects into my aggregation query I get 0 results. 
If I remove them, I get all the results.

```
collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDatabase").getCollection("testColletion");
collection.insertOne(new Document("testField","testValue"));
Bson addFields = Aggregates.addFields(new Field<>("cmp", new Document("$or", Arrays.asList(new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(1, 1))))));
Bson match = Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("cmp", 1));
AggregateIterable aggregationQuery = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$match", new Document("testField", "testValue")),
        addFields,
        match
));
boolean hasDocuments = aggregationQuery.iterator().hasNext()
```

Comment: Please explain why you need this.

Comment: can you show us the full code please, and how you pass the list?

Comment: @YCF_L I don't see how this is relevant here, but surely I can do that if you want. (one case-example is already shown in the code above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) on 3.6 mongo server version.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.addFields;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.match;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
```

Something like

```
Bson match = match(expr(new Document("$or", asList(new Document("$eq", asList(1, 1))))));
AggregateIterable aggregationQuery = collection.aggregate(asList(
                [...]
                match
));
```

This should output query something like

```
{ "$match" : { "$expr" : { "$or" : [{ "$eq" : [1, 1] }] } } }
```

For lower version 3.4 you can use combination of `$addFields` and `$match` to achieve the similar query.

```
Bson addFields = addFields(new Field<>("cmp", new Document("$or", asList(new Document("$eq", asList(1, 1))))));
Bson match = match(eq("cmp", true));
AggregateIterable aggregationQuery = collection.aggregate(asList(
               [...]
               addFields,
               match
));
```

This should output query something like

```
{ "$addFields" : { "cmp" : { "$or" : [{ "$eq" : [1, 1] }] } } }    
{ "$match" : { "cmp" : true } }
```

Comment: I used your first solution and received the error;
*unknown top level operator: $expr' on server*
My mongodb version is (gradle); 
`compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.6.3'`

Comment: You require the server version to be on 3.6 not the java driver version. Run db.version() in shell to check your version.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, check my update if you wish.

Comment: Yw. Fixed the answer. Please try now.

Answer (score 2):

In normal MongoDB Javascript queries you can express filters with `1=1`.

Here is an example:

```
db.customer.find(
  {"customer.id" : "1081965259", "customer.status": "Live", "$where": "1 == 1"}, 
  {"customer.id": 1, "customer.status": 1})
  .pretty();
```

The relevant query is `"$where": "1 == 1"`. If you set this to `"$where": "1 == 2"` never any results will be retrieved.

**Update**

You can also use this clause in an or statement:

```
db.customer.find({"$or": [{ "customer.id" : "1081959342" }, { "$where": "1 == 1" }]});
```

Beware: this returns literally all records in the collection.

**Update 2**

Actually the combination of the `$or` clause with the `$where` can also be done in Java as well as well as a simple and combination. Here is an example:

```
// Or Logic
private static FindIterable<Document> findDocumentByKeysOrClause(String id, MongoCollection<Document> collection) {
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    List<BasicDBObject> orQueryList =
            Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("customer.customerId.sourceKeys.keies.id", id),
                    new BasicDBObject("$where", "1 == 1"));
    query.put("$or", orQueryList);
    return collection.find(query);
}
```

Here is my full test class for reference:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Tests Mongo custom queries.
 */
public class MongoClauseTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("customers");
        MongoCollection<Document> customerCollection = db.getCollection("customer_UK");
        final FindIterable<Document> documentByKeysOrClause = findDocumentByKeysOrClause("C@0248870263@DHUB", customerCollection);
        MongoCursor<Document> iter = documentByKeysOrClause.iterator();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3 &&  iter.hasNext(); i++) {
            System.out.println(iter.next().toJson());
        }
    }

    // And logic
    private static FindIterable<Document> findDocumentByKeys(String id, MongoCollection<Document> collection) {
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("customer.customerId.sourceKeys.keies.id", id);
        query.put("$where", "1 == 1");
        return collection.find(query);
    }

    // Or Logic
    private static FindIterable<Document> findDocumentByKeysOrClause(String id, MongoCollection<Document> collection) {
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        List<BasicDBObject> orQueryList =
                Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("customer.customerId.sourceKeys.keies.id", id),
                        new BasicDBObject("$where", "1 == 1"));
        query.put("$or", orQueryList);
        return collection.find(query);
    }
}
```

Here is the version of the MongoDB driver which was used:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: do you have a mongo shell example using $or and '1=1' ?

Comment: Thanks for your input (I upvoted it), however the real problem lies on how we can write a query like the one you posted using Java.

Comment: I suspect you can just pass `"true"` instead of `"1 == 1"`. SQL has trouble with Boolean literals, Mongo should not.

Comment: Since MongoDB in Java is based on `Document(String field, Object value)` objects, I don't know how one could do that. If you have a working example, that would be great.

Comment: @koulini See my second update. You can represent this type of query in Java.

Comment: @gil.fernandes I applied your solution in a aggregation query:
`new Document("$match", new Document("$or",new Document("$where","1==1")))` but received an error:
*$where is not allowed inside of a $match aggregation expression*

Comment: @koulini Actually I have tested the code. I have updated the answer with the Maven version of the MongoDB driver. The MongoDB version used for the test was: version v3.4.3

Comment: @gil.fernandes Sorry, but I do not see your code using aggregation. Your code works, but only for `find` queries.